# How to pop up external link in bootstrap modal

Tags: bootstrap-4

Suppose I have an external link `https://example.com` for my site `https://my site.com`. How to pop up the external link in bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution. I think this code solve your problem.

For display of new link use `<iframe>` tag and add your site URL by using `src` path.

**Bootstrap Model**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      data-toggle="modal"
      data-target="#exampleModal"
    >
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="exampleModal"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe
              src="https://getbootstrap.com/"
              name="myIframe"
              class="w-100 h-100"
            ></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              data-dismiss="modal"
            >
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```